# VB.net 2008 print 2 or many forms using printform

Tags: vb.net, forms, printing

I am having a problem of printing 2 or more forms in Vb.net using printform control

example: I have form1 and form2 on my project. I manage to print form1. Now I want to print my form2 or shall we say make it as page two on my printpreview window.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

Here you go.

```
' Set PrintForm1 to user Form 2
PrintForm1.Form = My.Forms.Form2

' You have to Show and focus form2 to print it
Form2.Show()
Form2.Focus()

' Make PrintForm1 print the document
PrintForm1.Print()

' Close From2
Form2.Close()
```